# What if `items` and `type` were defined as arrays, without anyOf property

Tags: jsonschema

In the [core/validation meta-schema](http://json-schema.org/schema), `items` and `type` properties are defined as follow :

**items**

```
"items": {
    "anyOf": [
        { "$ref": "#" },
        {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": { "$ref": "#" }
        }
    ],
    "default": {}
},
```

**type**

```
"type": {
    "anyOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/simpleTypes" },
        {
            "type": "array",
            "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/simpleTypes" },
            "minItems": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true
        }
    ]
},
```

As I understand it :

- `items` can be a schema or an array of at least one schema
- `type` can be a `simpleType` or an array of at least one `simpleType`

Apart from the practicality and comfort of writing, am I right to consider that these definitions would be equivalent?

**items**

```
"items": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": { "$ref": "#" }
    "default": [{}]
},
```

**type**

```
"type": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/simpleTypes" },
    "uniqueItems": true
},
```

In other words, is there a difference in interpretation between the two following schemas :

**schema #1**

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "string"
    }
}
```

**schema #2**

```
{
    "type": ["array"],
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the "in other words" part:

- there is no semantic difference between `"type": "array"` and `"type": ["array"]`
- but the "items" are different:

  - `"items": {"type": "string"}` means an array with any number of string items
  - `"items": [{"type": "string"}]` means an array of any number of elements, where the 0th must be a string, the rest can be anything

You can find more about list vs tuple validation here: https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html